# AngularJS: $scope.$watch two values that depend on each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an AngularJS app with a date range where the end date always has to be 11 months after the start date (for a total duration of 12 months). The user needs to be able to go into the view and edit either the start or end date. So if they edit the start date, the end date adjusts to 11 months after the start date. And if they edit the end date, the start date adjusts to 11 months before the end date.

The problem is that when either of these dates change, they trigger an AJAX call to the server, but the way it's working now, they are triggering two calls because when one date changes, so does the other.

I'm trying use `$scope.$watch('startDate')` and `$scope.$watch('endDate')` to detect changes in my controller, but am struggling to find a way to change both values at once, but only trigger one AJAX server call.

Any ideas on how to keep both dates in line, but avoid duplicate AJAX calls and `$scope.$watch()` loops?

Comment: Can't you have the element used to change the date trigger a function instead of doing a watch?  Or better yet, have a save button that saves the new date ranges.

Comment: What are your dates, numerical timestamp, ios string, actual date object? What are you ajax calls for; separate for start and end, or can you batch them, etc?

Comment: @BenFelda I am using https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker/ but am unsure of how to add an `ng-change` or similar to that datepicker to trigger the function. Any ideas? I didn't really see anything relevant in the documentation.

Comment: @rgthree - They are actual date objects. My ajax call takes all the current parameters on the page (including the start and end dates) and makes a call to the server to return some data based on all those params. If I make an extra call it will be with invalid data (either start or end date will be temporarily incorrect) and so it would be a pointless call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to BenFelda's suggestion, I was able to piece together some code that did what I wanted using g00fy's datepicker and `ng-change`.

**view:**

```
<div ng-model="startDate" ng-change="startDateChanged()" date-picker="startDate" min-view="month"></div>
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.startDateChanged = function() {
    console.log('the start date changed!');
    console.log($scope.startDate);
    //make AJAX call, which only happens once
}
```